# Should I be able to call a <script> from a C# routine in a true behind page?

Tags: javascript, blazor, code-behind

I have a Blazor WebAssembly app with ASP.NET Core hosted, with my markup code in Index.razor and behind code in Index.razor.cs. Call me old fashioned.

I have the hookups between razor and razor.cs in place and working. My C# behind routines are found and work fine, EXCEPT those that make a call to a .

For example, the call:

await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("ShowAlert", showAlertMessage);

when included in a routine on the behind Index.razor.cs page, errors in compile on recognizing InvokeVoidAsyc.

I move the host C# routine to the markup Index.razor page, all is recognized and it works.

My question then, should I be able to call a  from a C# routine in a true behind page? Is there something else you have to do to make that work? I would really like to keep all my behind code in a razor.cs page.

Or is it only "hooked up" in a Blazor project like mine to be called from C# code hosted in the markup page?

It is cool that Blazor let's you mix and match to some extent.

Comment: Sorry, I should have used Javascript instead of the script code line - that got stripped out.  So where it reads like something is missing, insert script or javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Have you injected the

```
private readonly IJSRuntime jsRuntime;

protected override void OnInitialized(IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
{
    this.jsRuntime = jsRuntime;
    base.OnInitialized();
}
```

in the code behind as it cannot see the injected class if it is injected the markup page.

Comment: Thanks! I thought I had it covered with an [Inject] statement, but the OnInitialized completed it. Follow up question? Is this the routine i can use to initialize other variables prior to initial web page launch? My instance complained about "override"; removing that made it work.